# Power off video card until reboot from command line?

Tags: video, power-management, modprobe, graphic-card

I have "headless" machine with video card, I use very rarely, only if I want physical access to it. The cooler of this video card became old and started to produce bad noise.

Can I disable this video card in such a way, that it:

1. will turn on again on reboot
2. a cooler stop to rotate

I did:

```
lspci | grep VGA
sudo lspci -vs 01:00
```

To know it's module then I put:

```
blacklist radeon
```

into:

```
/etc/modprobe/blacklist.conf
```

But, this didn't work.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

First, look for Bus ID of the graphic card. A possible method is `lspci | grep VGA`. An output example is:

**XX:XX.X** VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b80 (rev a1)

Now, you can disable temporally this GPU assigning the value 1 in a file called “remove” inside the correct path of this PCI device. Changing XX with previous Bus ID values.

```
sudo echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:XX:XX.X/remove
```

This command will disable the GPU in runtime. A restart will put the GPU available again. I tested it with a Nvidia GPU in a CentOS 7 server. Maybe the path is different for other GPUs or GNU/Linux distributions. I hope this configuration disables the cooler too.

Comment: This caused directory disappear, but didn't stop the card cooler.

Comment: I'd say `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:XX:XX.X/remove` for non root